# Insert the getelementptr instruction

Tags: c, llvm, intermediate-code

I want to insert the `getelementpr` instruction in my code, like the one shown below.

```
%i1 = getelementptr inbounds [16 x i64]* @Counters, i64 0, i64 %8
```

How can I insert that? I can insert load and store instructions by using the constructors of `LoadInst` and `StoreInst` classes, but the constructor for `GetElementPtrInst` is declared private, so can't use it. So, my question is how to add this instruction from my code for an LLVM pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html you can create the instruction via factory-like `GetElementPtrInst::Create()` method. Alternatively, you can use `IRBuilder` to do all low-level stuff for you.